# Get JSON fieldnames without knowing the real names

Tags: java, json

I have a *JSON* Array, I wanted to create dynamically a no of `List<String> jsonFieldName` base on the no of unique fields in the JSON response; Say for eg;

```
JSON = [{a:1,b:2,c:3},{a:4,b:5,c:5}];
```

result:

```
temp_array=[{a,b,c}];
```

based on the JSON sample above, I would end up with 3 new List;
list:
list a
list b
list c

I wanted to end up like these because, I wanted to create a generic JSON response parser wherein each response could differ in size/length.

How can I implement one in Android;

Here's my existing method for parsing the JSON response

```
public void getJsonData(JSONArray ja) {
    try {
        // JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); ++i) {
            JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.i("Connect->getJsonData", jo.getString("tableno"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ConnectToDatabase->getJsonData", "Error Parsing JSON Data "
                + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: link is good, JsonObject.names(); does the trick... now how do I accept the answer that is just a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did:

```
public void getJsonData(JSONArray ja) {
 **List<String> arrNames = new ArrayList<String>**;
 try {
    // JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
    for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); ++i) {
        JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
        **arrNames[i] = jo.names(i);**
        Log.i("Connect->getJsonData", jo.getString("tableno"));
    }
 } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("ConnectToDatabase->getJsonData", "Error Parsing JSON Data "
            + e.toString());
 }
}
```